# Export XCode App for One Person

Tags: xcode, macos

Alright so I've built my first desktop app in xcode. The app is intended for use by one person only. I want to export it in the quickest, easiest way possible so they can use it on their laptop.

I've got Mac OS 10.10.3 and XCode 6.4. The target laptop has Mac OS 10.10.5. I am reluctant to update my system and the one on the laptop but will do if I have no other choice.

Getting it to work on my own computer would be a great start. Currently if I do Product > Archive. And then Export "As Mac Application" (unsigned). It creates the app but when I try and open it, it say "App couldn't open because of a problem". Is there a way I can debug this? Or an obvious thing I may have missed?

Ideally I want the app to work on my computer and to be able to transfer it to the target laptop and have it work on there too. I'll pay for the developer licence if I have no other choice but for a single-target application I feel like it's a waste of money.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say it explicitly in your question but do you not have an apple developer certificate?  If not, then you will not likely be able to sign the app appropriately to export it for use.  If I'm not mistaken, when I export my apps (even for local testing on other machines in my house) the app gets signed with my developer certificate, enabling OSX to see that the app has been signed by a registered developer.

I believe you will be able to run the app in Xcode (without a developer certificate), but in order to export it you need a signature (development certificate) which is provided as part of the Apple Developer subscription.

Comment: An unsigned or self-signed application would trigger an "unknown developer" warning, but not the error described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

An easy thing you could try to do, assuming your app builds:

1. Run your app
2. Right click the app icon in the dock
3. Click Options -> Show in Finder
4. Boom there's your app bundle.  Send that over to your recipient

Comment: It doesn't open, check question

Comment: I did :\  you said you tried to Archive.  I am saying you shouldn't need to archive/export it.  If you can run it, there will be an app bundle on your disk that you can copy pasta

Comment: I don't have your project, or your environment, so it's hard for me to test what would/would not work for you-- I'm just suggesting to you what works for the current app I am building

Comment: That ended with the same result anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems fairly obvious in hindsight but I ended up installing XCode on the target computer (using [the Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) to get the same version as I was running on the dev computer. I was then able to just copy the project across and run it. This wasn't ideal but it did the job.